# How do I stop after_create callback that interacts with an external API from being executed when running rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, callback

I have a Rails model with an `after_create` callback, that has code which interacts with an external API. That code is getting executed and content on another app is being created when I run rspec tests.

I want to do something such as:

```
after_create :external_api_code, unless: testing? 

def testing? 
  #what goes here to recognize that the object is being created in a test? 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether or not code is running in the test environment:

```
Rails.env.test?
```

To avoid running external API code in RSpec, put this in your configuration block:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    allow_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:external_api_code).and_return(return_value)
  end
end
```

To actually run the code in the test that needs it run:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:external_api_code).and_call_original
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solution may be to just stub the external_api_code in all tests and unstub it where its call is really needed. Of course this solution will work but it requires some monkey business because you have to place the stubbing code in all test files of your project. This is possible RSpec code to do it:

```
before(:all) do
    User.any_instance.stub(:external_api_code)
end
```

like this in your model test case file.